# creating html button from javascript with onClick call a method with one param

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Im creating html buttons from javascript vía ajax. When I press an html button it will call an ajax function. 
If ajax succeed, it will get a number that will be used in a for loop. 
The loop will start and in each iteration it will create an html button with onclick property calling the same method but with diferent number in param. If we are in the third iteration, then `c == 2` and the param will be equal to two:

```
function doAdCashAjax(){

    $.ajax({
        url : '../controller/ajaxController.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            action:'getNumber'
        },
        success : function(data) {
            //Creates a button for each campaign 
            for(var c = 0;c<data;c++){

                var btn = document.createElement('input');
                btn.setAttribute("id", "Campaign "+c);
                btn.type = "button";
                btn.setAttribute("value","Campaign "+c);
                btn.setAttribute("name",c);
                btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
                    getCampaign(c);
                });
                document.body.appendChild(btn);

            }
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert ('error: ' + textStatus + ' errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the method the html buttons are calling for now:

```
function getCampaign(campIndex){
    $.ajax({
        url : '../controller/ajaxController.php',
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            action:'setCampaign',
            campIndex:campIndex,
        },
        success : function(data) {
            alert('campaign index: '+campIndex);
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert ('error: ' + textStatus + ' errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

All the buttons are being created successfully, but when I click them, I get a successful ajax and the alert outputs is always index = 10 whatever button I press. I would like to ask here how to do to set the correct parameter in the function call, because I will need to call the function from different buttons with different params.

Optionally I would like to understand why `getCampaign(campIndex)` outputs 10 which is the value of `data` in `doAdCashAjax()`. Also optionally but welcome, when I use the inspector to see the dynamically created html buttons I can see the id, the type, the value and the name properties but never the onClick property.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is about `scope`. All click event handlers will take the last value of `c`. You should make this way:

```
for(var c = 0 ; c<11; c++)
{
    ....
    makeFunc(btn, c);
    ....
}
function makeFunc(btn, c)
{
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
        getCampaign(c);
    });
}
```

Example: https://jsbin.com/wecujoburu/edit?js,output